# How to use Dialogflow outside of the Web Console

Tags: dialogflow-es

Is it possible to create a Dialogflow Agent outside of the Dialogflow Web Console?

Is there maybe some Web API I can call that can create an 'Intent'?
And then maybe some other API that can add an 'Event' to that 'Intent'?
And then maybe more API's to add in a 'Training phrase' / 'Action' or 'Parameter'?

I've seen; I can click on the 'Settings' button for my 'Agent' then there is a tab: "Export and Import" and under that tab are buttons: 'Export as ZIP', 'Restore from ZIP' and 'Import from ZIP'.

Can I use those features somehow to write my own ZIP file. Then just import it using: 'Import from ZIP'?

Any help or other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/manage-intents documentation page, which contains examples in multiple languages.

A sample JSON would look like:

```
{
  "displayName": "ListRooms",
  "priority": 500000,
  "webhookState": "WEBHOOK_STATE_UNSPECIFIED",
  "trainingPhrases": [
    {
      "type": "EXAMPLE",
      "parts": [
        {
          "text": "What rooms are available at 10am today?"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "action": "listRooms",
  "messages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Here are the available rooms:"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Iron Bishop :D. This is exactly the stuff I'm looking for.